# How to hide NullPointer Warnings (due to NoArgsConstructor with force=true) in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, warnings, dropwizard, lombok, weld

I have created a Java application using Dropwizard and Weld. I have also included Lombok and I have currently annotated my service classes like:

```
@Slf4j
@ApplicationScoped
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Inject}))
public class MovieRequestService {

    private final MovieService movieService;
    private final ActorService actorService;
```

It works fine and I am happy with it. The RequiredArgsConstructor is useful for my Unit tests. The NoArgsConstructor is necessary for Weld. force = true has to be set because of the final keywords... But this also leads to the fact that IntelliJ warns me on every single place where I use the movieService or actorService....

What should I do? Can I get rid of the warnings?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Force=true" parameter of @NoArgsConstructor annotation means that fields are initialized to @Nullable value, so the warnings of "Constant conditions & exceptions" inspection (Java | Probable bugs | Constant conditions & exceptions) about possible NullPointerException are correct. You may disable the inspection's option "Report problems that happen only on some code paths" to get rid of the warning.

Comment: How do I find this option? Going in IntelliJ settings -> Editor -> Inspections, I cannot find "Report problems that happen only on some code paths" using the search field.

Comment: And yes, the warning is correct. But in my case Weld takes care of this and calls all those constructors in a way so that for later usage everything is not null. So in my case and in my project, I would like to skip these warnings - preferably only in exact this context (i.e. skip warning if it is a final field variable and the class is annotated with @ApplicationScoped, @NoArgsConstructor(force = true), @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Inject})) )

Comment: Please go to "Hector" inspector in right bottom corner -> Configure inspections -> find the inspection "Constant conditions & exceptions", inspection's options will be to the right, the mentioned one will be the last one.

Comment: This works as expected. Thank you. But still it also removes Warnings like the Nullpointer Warning in this case:

        String s = null;
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            s = "hello";
        }
        int len = s.length();
which will throw Nullpointers in 50% of all cases...